# How can I use NodeJS to retrieve data from Oracle SQL Database?

Tags: node.js, oracle

I am new to node and I am trying to create a node application to connect to the oracle database and retrieve the data. I have looked all over the internet and cannot seem to figure out how to do it. Here is my current server.js file, but when I try to run node server.js I get this long error message:

Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "The specified module could not be found". See https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html for help
Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html
You must have 64-bit Oracle Client libraries in your PATH environment variable.If you do not have Oracle Database on this computer, then install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from
https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html
A Microsoft Visual Studio Redistributable suitable for your Oracle client library version must be available.

Where do I begin?

server.js code:

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');

oracledb.getConnection(
    {
        user          : "",
        password      : "",
        connectString : ""
    },
    connExecute
);

function connExecute(err, connection) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        return;
    }
}

function connRelease(connection) {
    connection.close(
        function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err.message);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: _"Where do I begin?"_   With the error messages.  "_You must have 64-bit Oracle Client libraries in your PATH environment variable."_   So did you confirm that?

Comment: Yes, I have the 64-bit oracle client downloaded and updated my paths but it did not get rid of the error

Answer (score 0):

Try this from the [node-oracledb Windows installation instructions](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#instwin):

```
  const oracledb = require('oracledb');
  try {
    oracledb.initOracleClient({libDir: 'C:\\oracle\\instantclient_19_14'});
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Whoops!');
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
```

Also look at all the node-oracledb [examples](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/tree/master/examples) and [documentation](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html).  You will find it easier to use the async/await style of coding instead of callbacks.

A sample is:

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const dbConfig = { user: 'hr', password: 'welcome', connectString: 'localhost/orclpdb1' };

if (process.platform === 'darwin') {
  oracledb.initOracleClient({libDir: process.env.HOME + '/Downloads/instantclient_19_8'});
} else if (process.platform === 'win32') {
  oracledb.initOracleClient({libDir: 'C:\\oracle\\instantclient_19_14'});
}

let sql, binds, options, result;
sql = `SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI') AS D FROM DUAL`;
binds = [];
options = { outFormat: oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT };

async function run() {
  let connection;

  try {
    connection = await oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig);

    result = await connection.execute(sql, binds, options);
    console.dir(result, { depth: null });

  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    if (connection) {
      try {
        await connection.close();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
}

run();
```